# Symfony Not able to insert record for Bidirectional onetoOne relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, one-to-one

I have two tables `User` and `Survey` a user can only fill in one survey so the relationship I have setup between the two is `Bidirectional` `onetoOne`

The flow of the app is that user has to register first and then fill the survey, the registration goes just fine.

The problem I am having is when a user try to save the survey he gets the following error

> [1/2] PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`mv2`.`mv_survey`, CONSTRAINT `FK_E81A494BBF396750` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id`) REFERENCES `mv_users` (`survey_id`))

I am using `YML` and not `annotations` so here are my `orm.yml` files for user and survey

**User**

```
UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: mv_users
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 255
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        email:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
        role:
            type: string
            length: 255
        password:
            type: string
            length: 255
        salt:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        isActive:
            type: boolean
        survey_id:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
    oneToOne:
        survey_allias:
            targetEntity: XYZBundle\Entity\survey
            joinColumn:
                name: survey_id
                referencedColumnName: id

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Survey**

```
XYZBundle\Entity\survey:
    type: entity
    table: mv_survey
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        gender:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        dob:
            type: date
            nullable: true
        postcode:
            type: integer
            nullable: true            
        userID:
            type: integer
            column: user_id
    oneToOne:
        user_allias:
            targetEntity: UserBundle\Entity\User
            inversedBy: survey_allias
            joinColumn:
                name: id
                referencedColumnName: survey_id

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I know I should probably use Fixtures but just to test that everything is working inside the controller is self I am doing this to insert the data

```
$survey = new Survey();
$survey->setGender('Male');
$survey->setDob(new \DateTime());
$survey->setUserID('1');
$manager->persist($survey);
$manager->flush();
```

Which gives an error of

> [1/2] PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`mv2`.`mv_survey`, CONSTRAINT `FK_E81A494BBF396750` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id`) REFERENCES `mv_users` (`survey_id`))

I will really appreciate any help on this, I have even dropped the entire database schema and recreated it as suggested by other posts but that did not help either, what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$survey->setUserID('1');

This is bad practice. You should set the entity directly.

This is how you should do it :

**User orm.yml**

You don't need the surveyID property neither in your orm.yml or in your entity.

```
oneToOne:
    survey:
        targetEntity: XYZBundle\Entity\survey
        mappedBy: user
```

**User Entity**

```
protected $survey;

public function setSurvey(Survey $survey)
{
    $this->survey = $survey;
}

public function getSurvey()
{
    return $this->survey;
}
```

**Survey orm.yml**

You don't need the userID property neither in your orm.yml or in your entity.

```
oneToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: UserBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: survey
        joinColumn:
            name: survey_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

**Survey Entity**

```
protected $user;

public function setUser(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

Take the habit to let Doctrine handle the foreign keys and stuff. All your entities have to implement for relations are setters/getters directly for entities (not ids) :

$entity1->setEntity2($entity2);

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you please elaborate what is `$entity1->setEntity2($entity2);`

Comment: My point is just that you have to let Doctrine handle your relationships.

A relationship is just one object to another so your entities properties / getters / setters should be object related, not ids related.

So don't do that :
     `$entity1->setEntity2ID($entity2->getId());`
But this : `$entity1->setEntity2($entity2);`

Comment: Sorry I am lost and I am trying to wrap my head around it, so this is what I think should happen. I dont think I need a survey_id column anymore in user table as long as I can link the user table (column: id) with survey table (column: user_id). This gives me onetoOne relationship, so when a user fills in a survey how do i set the `user_id` column in survey table, my setters and getters are set exactly like yours but nothing is saved in user_id column, just a null.

Comment: Can you put your whole code in a gist for me to check ?

Comment: Here is a fixed gist : https://gist.github.com/Babacooll/24cb84baf5c24329ee07. You just forgot in your controller to setUser() on your Survey.